# Syncing text and audio with jQuery/javascript, more efficiently?

Tags: java, jquery, audio, synchronization, jplayer

I've been syncing some text with audio, using jPlayer and jQuery's .fadeIn/.fadeOut. It works as expected, using these if statements:

```
var currentTime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime)

if (currentTime > 1){
    $("#slide1").fadeIn("fast");             
} else if (currentTime < 1){
    $("#slide1").fadeOut("fast"); 
}

if (currentTime >= 9 && currentTime < 49){
    $("#slide2").fadeIn("fast"); 
} else if (currentTime < 9){
    $("#slide2").fadeOut("fast");   
}
```

and so on. This will show/hide div's at the proper time and allow for scrubbing. The code I have adapted is from [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7518/has-anyone-been-able-to-convert-a-sites-media-content-from-flash-to-html5). I am a designer who knows a  little programming, so my skills aren't great but I understand a lot. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this, instead of copy/pasting the if statement as there will be A LOT of them. Possibly an array of all the in/out times? I'm not sure how to do it.

Best case scenario would be to have an xml list of times control prebuilt divs (I think anyway). Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks for your time, 
S

## Update

Ok, I've made some progress, but am having problems with the XML/loop. I have added content to the XML and have it dynamically generating divs. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Slides>
<Slide id="#slide1" in="1" out="9999" content="Implications"></Slide>
<Slide id="#slide2" in="9" out="49" content="Implications have the form"></Slide>
<Slide id="#slide3" in="11" out="49" content="If A is true, then B is true."></Slide>
</Slides>
```

and here is my code that creates the divs (that are hidden)

```
<script>
var mySlides = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});
function parseXml(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("Slide").each(function() {
        $("#slides").append("<div class=\"starthidden\" id=" + $(this).attr("id") + ">" + $(this).attr("content") + "</div>");
    });
    var $slides = xml.find('Slide');
    for (var i = 0, len = $slides.length; i < len; i++) {
        mySlides[mySlides.length] = {
            in  : $slides.eq(i).attr('in'),
            out : $slides.eq(i).attr('out')
        };
    }
}
$("#audio").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) { 
    var currentTime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime)
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (currentTime >= mySlides[i].in && currentTime < mySlides[i].out) {
            $(mySlides[i].id).fadeIn("fast");
        } else if (currentTime < mySlides[i].in) {
            $(mySlides[i].id).fadeOut("fast");
        }
    }   
});
</script>
```

I guess I just don't really know where to go from here to get the divs to show/hide now? As well, I've got to figure out a way to turn many divs off as well, as ***slides*** are actually lines, not full slides so I need to clear them off the stage (if you see in the XML, it would be at 49sec). Can anyone help? Thanks so much. 
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup an array of objects that store information for each slide.

```
//setup an array of objects that store information for each caption
var mySlides = [
        {
            id  : '#slide1',//set a string reference to the element to fade
            in  : 1,//start time
            out : 9999//end time (this is long so it doesn't fade out ever)
        },
        {
            id  : '#slide2',
            in  : 9,
            out : 49
        }
    ], len = mySlides.length;

//loop through the slides to check if they should be faded in/out
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (currentTime >= mySlides[i].in && currentTime < mySlides[i].out) {
        $(mySlides[i].id).fadeIn("fast");
    } else if (currentTime < mySlides[i].in) {
        $(mySlides[i].id).fadeOut("fast");
    }
}
```

### Update

If your XML file is something like this:

```
<slides>
    <slide id="#slide1" in="1" out="9999"></slide>
    <slide id="#slide2" in="9" out="49"></slide>
</slides>
```

Then you can grab the XML file using AJAX and parse it for it's data like this:

```
var mySlides = [];
$.ajax({
    url      : 'path/to/file.xml',
    type     : 'get',
    dataType : 'xml',
    success  : function (serverResponse) {
        var $slides = serverResponse.find('slide');
        for (var i = 0, len = $slides.length; i < len; i++) {
            mySlides[mySlides.length] = {
                id  : $slides.eq(i).attr('id'),
                in  : $slides.eq(i).attr('in'),
                out : $slides.eq(i).attr('out')
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Do you know if this would be more/less taxing on the browser as there will be *possibly* hundreds and also, is there a way to read this data (id/in/out) from an xml file?

Comment: @user1183442 The loop itself won't create much overhead. I added an **update** with an example of pulling the data in from a XML file. An up-vote or accepted-answer-vote would be appreciated if you found this answer helpful.

Comment: I can't seem to up-vote because I don't have enough 'reputation'. I selected your answer as the correct answer though! I haven't figured it all out yet, but I really appreciate your help! I added an update, if you have any more input it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to have two different functions for your `for` loops. One function to parse the XML into an object and another one to update the visible slides when the video is playing. You can either bind to some type of `onTime` event for your video player or just run an interval that runs the second function to update what's currently being viewed. Since the data you are saving for the slides is in seconds (one second, fourty-nine seconds, etc.) you can just set an interval to run every second and update what should be visible. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to put them in 2 separate functions but just couldn't get it to work. A little beyond my level. I'll keep trying and reading what I can. Thanks for you help (updated code above)!
S

Answer (score 1):

with your page content i would include some JSON (using Japser's structure, forget XML) detailing the messages and their in/out points..

then, in a handler for jPlayer's `timeupdate` event (called every 250ms), examine `event.jPlayer.status.currentTime` and determine which message from your JSON should currently be displayed.